# Set & get custom CUSTOMER ATTRIBUTE in Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento

We create a custom customer attribute in Magento Enterprise (1.12.0.2) to store the users account id, thus allowing us to keep our RMS in sync with Magento.

I need to set the RMS id manually (via PHP), and then later get the RMS id. The custom attribute is a text field and it's label is rms_id. I need to do the following:

1. Check if rms_id is set using customer id
2. If it's not set, update the customers rms_id with a provided value

Seems straightforward, however I'm new to Magento development and cannot find a solution to this problem. All searches return results for custom *product* attributes, which is not the asme as a custom *customer* attribute. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Magic methods should still be working for customer attributes. `$_cutomer->getRmsId()` - If not, make sure the attribute is part of the collection/model object. This may be of use: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */    
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load({customer id});

if (!$customer->getRmsId()) {
    $customer->setRmsId({value});
    //the original version of this answer was wrong; need to use the resource model.
    $customer->getResource()->saveAttribute($customer,'rms_id');
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly with the exception of the save method. Apparently Magento didn't like saveAttribute and threw a nasty error, so I swapped it out with $customer->save(); and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to load a single customer using the rms id? The ideal solution would be something like $customer->loadByRmsId($rms_id);

Comment: there is no saveAttribute() method in $customer model. You should use
$customer->getResource()->saveAttribute($customer,'rms_id');
@NickParsons

Comment: Mage Customer Model Customer does not have a saveAttribute function. NickParson's answer is the correct one.